# Gradle wont run project if the source code loads a file

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

So i have a project where i load a file:

```
file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.osm").getFile());
```

and after doing gradlew clean build, gradlew run
it gets stuck on this for eternity (atleast 2 hours before i killed it)

> Task :Main.main()
>
> C:\Users\Lucas\IdeaProjects\BFST20Gruppe8\src\main\resources\test.osm

If I comment out the line loading the file it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Triby https://imgur.com/1e4KY2q it spams this for hours if i just let it run
i have tried messing with my jvm args and used --offline but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid, my project was running and stuck in a loop, and i just didnt know how gradle works